# How to display the same file over the browser even if the file has been changed on the server?

Tags: php, cookies

I am uploading a file(Image) on the server, and saving it with one unique name. Now previewing it on the browser where file fetched from the server.

Now, I changed the file(image), but save with that previous unique name only. But, while previewing it, browser is showing previous file.

I figured it out as a cookie problem. So after deleting cookie from the browser manually, I were able to see the new file.

Comment: How are you rendering the file? Are you directly calling it (server.com/my_uploads/uniquefilename.png) or are you using a handler? (server.com/view_image.php?image=unqiuefilename.png)? If the latter, you can use `header()` and set Expiration/cache directives for the client (forcing their browser to re-grab the file and not use a local copy).

Comment: This is hardly a cookie issue. More likely a browser cache issue. As quick test, append some unique value (timestamp?) to the query string of image's URL.

Comment: We are all beginners, in one way or another. It's OK, just ask away :)

Comment: @Brad I am calling the file directly from the server, given the path name.

Comment: @hari: Then it's a cache issue. Try using `move_uploaded_file` and adding a `mktime()` to the file name or making the file name unique in some way. Or, play around with server headers setting the `Expires:` header to some time in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a caching issue, not cookie. You might have cleared your browser cache as well when you cleared your cookie, so the new image appeared.

You might want to check your server configuration for caching expiration header.

If you don't know how to change it (I can't show you how because it depends on your server environment), pressing **Ctrl + F5** on your browser to perform a no-cache refresh might help you see your new image right away.